# Chronicle Queue - Failed to acquire exclusive lock on the table store file

Tags: chronicle-queue

I am using chronicle-bom 5.21.96. While doing a write to the queue, running into the following error.

```html
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to claim exclusive exclusive lock on file /LargeBuffer/bawnmspc_BAW_CDC_EBS_PK_BAW_CDC_EBS_PK/4294163802/metadata.cq4t
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.table.SingleTableStore.doWithLock(SingleTableStore.java:160) ~[chronicle-queue-5.21.96.jar:?]
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.table.SingleTableStore.doWithExclusiveLock(SingleTableStore.java:125) ~[chronicle-queue-5.21.96.jar:?]
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.table.SingleTableBuilder.build(SingleTableBuilder.java:137) ~[chronicle-queue-5.21.96.jar:?]
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.initializeMetadata(SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.java:444) ~[chronicle-queue-5.21.96.jar:?]
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.preBuild(SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.java:1077) ~[chronicle-queue-5.21.96.jar:?]
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.build(SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.java:327) ~[chronicle-queue-5.21.96.jar:?]
```

What can cause this issue ? Also I see that this issue was closed on the chronicle-forums
( https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue/issues/641 ). Any help is appreciated on how to get past this error and an explanation as to what might cause this.

Answer (score 0):

The version 5.21.96 is an older stable version. However, there have been some fixes in this area. I suggest trying 5.23.37 or 5.24ea27